# how to pass state values as props to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass some constant values which is stored in state of parent component to child component and would like to pass down in tree.

1. is it right to store the constant values in state of App.tsx or any other suggestion
2. how can i access for example GrTag or sTag from App.tsx to Subchild component.

App.tsx

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        sTag : "00D",
        pTag : "010",
        adTag : "020",
        dbTag : "030",
        GrTag : "040",
        serTag : "00E",
        modTag : "060",
        iTag: "018"
      };
  }
  render() {
        return(
          <div >
            <Child {...this.state}/>  //is this right way to pass
          </div>
        );
  }
}
```

Child.tsx

```
class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
      return(
        <div>
        {
          <Subchild />    //want to pass the state values from App.tsx 
        }
        </div>
      );
  };
}
```

Subchild.tsx

```
class Subchild extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
      return(
        <div>
        {
            // want to print sTag value here
        }
        </div>
      );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are spreading the state `{...this.state}` will pass all the state values as props to the child components . If you need all the state values in your `Child` component as props then what you are doing is fine .

But if you just need the `stag` from the `App` inside the subChild then you can do

```
<Child {...this.state}/>
```

In your Child.tsx

```
<Subchild {...this.props} />
```

Comment: oh sorry, i would need to access all the values defined in state value of app in Subchild.tsx

Comment: i tried this and tried to access in child component itself for example GrTag but returned undefined.

Comment: you need to spread the props on the SubChild.  `<Subchild {...this.props} />`

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, pass the props from the child to the sub child. Like this;

```
class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
      return(
        <div>
        {
          <Subchild {...this.props}/>    //want to pass the state values from App.tsx 
        }
        </div>
      );
  };
}
```

But mind you. This is not a good way to pass data to components.
If you have data that can be shared amongst many components in your app, consider using *REACT REDUX* or *MOBX*. I personally recommmend using Redux.

Comment: so i child component i tried to print console log for {...this.props} i am not getting state values from App.tsx unfortunately. am i doing somehting wrong

Comment: Yes. You actually passed the subchild state instead of props

Answer (score 1):

App.tsx

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    sTag : "00D",
    pTag : "010",
    adTag : "020",
    dbTag : "030",
    GrTag : "040",
    serTag : "00E",
    modTag : "060",
    iTag: "018"
  };
}
render() {
    return(
     const data = this.state;
      <div >
        <Child dataToClid = {data}/>  //is this right way to pass
      </div>
    );
 }
}
```

Child.tsx

```
class Child extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
        data: this.props.dataToClid
    }
 }
 render(){
  const data = this.state;
  return(
    <div>
    {
      <Subchild dataToSubClid = {data}/>    //want to pass the state values from App.tsx 
    }
    </div>
  );
 };
}
```

SubChild.tsx

```
class Subchild extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
        data: this.props.dataToSubClid
     }
  }
  render(){
    const {GrTag, sTag} = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
       <p>{GrTag}</p>
       <p>{sTag}</p>
      </div>
    );
 };
}
```

you can do this way or you can use **[Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for pass data from parent to child**

Comment: will give this a try